# Swift - Open ViewController on Tapping a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a tableView with identical cells. After selecting one of them I would like to open another ViewController. 
I tried this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let destination = EditViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)

}
```

but it didn't open another ViewController. 
Can You give me a hint?

Comment: Have you embedded view controller with navigation controller inside storyboard ?

Comment: "didn't work" == no change or blank screen or ...?

Comment: I mean: no change

Comment: Check if the navigationController is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you just don't have the `navigationController` there - use rather `present` to show the viewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let destination = EditViewController()
    self.present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Or if you want the viewController to be pushed, make sure that you embed the `tableViewController` into a `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

Just go inside you storyboard, Select you initiate view controller, Then click on Editor > Embedded In and select Navigation controller, Then Your code will be work. This mean you have set the navigation stack for your view controllers from initial view controller.